# Rails undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class, Agile web development, task G,

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails. When i read the task G , check out section, of Agile web development with rails. I get a very strange problem.

> /home/chenhao/ruby/depot/app/views/orders/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:
>
> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

I guess the nil @order induce this error,but i have already initialized the @order in the new method of the controller. Could anyone help me slove this strange bug?

Here is the _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name, :size=>40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :address, :row=>3, :col=>40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, :size=>40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :pay_type %><br />
    <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES, :prompt=>"Select a payment method" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Place Order"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is the controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @orders }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  # GET /orders/new.json
  def new
    @cart = current_cart
    if @cart.line_items.empty?
      redirect_to store_url, :notice => 'Your cart is empty'
      return
    end
  
    @order = Order.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @order }
    end
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
        session[:cart_id] = nil

        format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: 'Thank you for your order.' }
        format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        @cart = current_cart
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /orders/1
  # PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

And the model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destory

  attr_accessible :address, :email, :name, :pay_type
  PAYMENT_TYPES = ["Check", "Credit card","Purchase Order"]

  validates :address, :email, :name, :presence => true
  validates :pay_type, :inclusion => PAYMENT_TYPES

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
        item.cart_id = nil
        line_items << item
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Seems ok to me, just confirm if you reassign `@order to nil` somewhere in `new.html.erb`

Comment: make sure that any other view that calls this partial has declared an `@order`

Comment: What action are you calling when you have this error?

Comment: is this happening on page load? or happening after posting form to controller?

Comment: This is happening on page load. However, i solve this problem by just restarting the rails server.I still don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with `form_tag` instead of `form_for`.

Or add `resources :orders` in your `routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem, i mistaken removed @order = Order.new from def new in orders_controller.rb